# Trouble installing secondary dependencies on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Has anyone seen this before? Below are the output logs that occur when I try to push to heroku ever since adding a new dependency, pysendy.

Note that pysendy requires the module 'requests' and thus I have also added requests to my requirements.txt.  If you look at the top of the logs carefully you'll see that the requests module is downloaded & unpacked during the dyno startup, but pysendy doesn't see it.  I even tried putting 'requests' at the top of the requirements.txt and nothing changed.  Heroku rejects the app.  I can get around this by manually importing pysendy into my project because it is small, but that sort of defeats the point of having dependencies.

My suspicion is that something about the request module dependency's installation isn't complete when pysendy tries to access the requests module.

### Requirements.txt:

```
requests==2.2.1

Django==1.6.2
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
djangorestframework==2.3.13
gunicorn==18.0
psycopg2==2.5.2

pysendy==0.0.3
pystache==0.5.3

static==1.0.2
```

### Output Logs:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python runtime (python-3.4.0)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.5.4)
       Downloading/unpacking requests==2.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
       Downloading/unpacking pysendy==0.0.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
         Downloading pysendy-0.0.3.tar.gz
         Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy/setup.py) egg_info for package pysendy
           Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
             File "/tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
               version = __import__('pysendy').__version__
             File "/tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy/pysendy/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
               from .pysendy import *
             File "/tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy/pysendy/pysendy.py", line 3, in <module>
               import requests
           ImportError: No module named 'requests'
           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
           Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

         File "/tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy/setup.py", line 5, in <module>

           version = __import__('pysendy').__version__

         File "/tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy/pysendy/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

           from .pysendy import *

         File "/tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy/pysendy/pysendy.py", line 3, in <module>

           import requests

       ImportError: No module named 'requests'

       ----------------------------------------
       Cleaning up...
       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_u37993/pysendy
       Storing debug log for failure in /app/.pip/pip.log

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `pysendy` is trying to use `requests` during its installation, and despite having it in it's installation requirements (see https://github.com/thiagofa/pysendy/blob/master/setup.py) it's still not being installed. This is clearly an upstream bug since it reproduces on a clean virtual env.

A workaround could be to push an initial `requirements.txt` with `pysendy` commented out, let it complete, thus fully installing `requests`, and then push the full version again to Heroku.

Comment: The workaround worked for me...clever idea to separate them.  Thank you!

Still, it seems like the work around should not be required and I'm concerned that when scaling the dyno count, the new dynos will want to install requests and pysendy at the same time, which will trigger the same error.

Comment: Heroku caches your compiled slugs so there's no reason it should ever compile them from scratch again. The longer term solution would be to fix the problem upstream. Since it reproduces on a clean virtualenv as well.